# Retrieving a file from NSBundle

Tags: ios, nsbundle

I am currently trying to integrate a library into my ios application. The library has something like this in it

```
  // Serve files from the standard Sites folder
    NSString *docRoot = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"web"] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

Now I believe this locates the `index.html` in the directory web. I do have a the web folder with index.html in it. However I am not sure where the ios application looks for the folder web. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the directory is readable

**Reference:**

```
+ (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)bundlePath
```

**Return Value**
The full pathname for the resource file or nil if the file could not be located. This method also returns nil if the bundle specified by the bundlePath parameter does not exist or is not a readable directory.

Answer (score 0):

From the `NSBundle pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)bundlePath` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:), the `bundlePath` parameter corresponds to:

> The path of a top-level bundle directory. This must be a valid path. For example, to specify the bundle directory for a Mac app, you might specify the path /Applications/MyApp.app.

In that case, your web folder should be located in your `/MyApp/MyApp/` directory.

There are some examples on how the [Bundle search pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-SW7) works and locates resources.

Comment: I placed the web folder right next to `.xcodeproj` file. However its still not being picked up

Comment: Did you add the folder to your project using add files to <Project>?

Comment: By adding the folder using the method above, the folder will be located inside your <Project> folder instead of next to .xcodeproj.